# Add a custom field to course Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I'm new to moodle. I need your suggestions to create plugin which will add a custom field on Add/edit courses page and will also store the input value in `mdl_course` table.

Comment: You should be able to do this from settings: http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/User_profile_fields

Comment: You can create new moodle course format. And add new fields in it. https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_formats

Comment: Moodle 3.7 already have that option.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5mhgTiWcWg

Answer (score 0):

As of now Moodle **does not** allow you to add custom fields to a course from the web interface.

However there is a patch available for v1.9 in the Moodle Tracker([MDL-18319](http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-18319)).

Please be aware that the patch is for Moodle-1.9 and applying it directly may corrupt your source code if you are using Moodle version > 1.9

Comment: Hi , custom field creation option is available in moodle 3.1.3 ??